# Optimising Polymer performance & avoiding memory leaks

Tags: polymer

In angular you can optimise some aspects of performance by being careful about the number of watches in use and careful use of ng repeats + avoiding certain memory leaks (ie jQuery listeners).  What are the most important aspects of optimising Polymer performance and avoiding memory leaks?